# Python script web service timeout

Tags: python

We have had a Python script running for many months now that simply scans through a directory of files, and posts each file to our web site via a web service call. The web site is also written in Python.

For no apparent reason, this morning this script started throwing the following error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')>
```

The site itself is up and running just fine. There are no indications of any errors. The developer that was working on this site is no longer with us, and we do not have a strong Python developer on staff as we are moving away from that.

Before I do an all nighter and rewrite this thing in C#, I wanted to see if anyone had any experience dealing with this issue. I do know that the script is connecting to a secure site (HTTPS), so I am not sure if something has come up with that, and I honestly dont know where to look to determine that. As I said before, the site itself isn't showing any signs of error, including SSL.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think if it was working up until this point the suspect is not the code but the site.  However, you may want to dig around in the code and write some debugging.  The urllib2 module method urlopen throws the object URLError as you can see and has an attribute 'reason'.  Beyond that I am not sure what you might do to debug the issue.  Check the credentials or the certs?  Its very possible the cert has expired or something has happened with that.  More likely than the code being the issue given its been working all this time.